# Combining two conditionals using AND in Makefile.am

Tags: makefile, configure, autotools, automake

Is it possible to have something like below in a Makefile.am?

```
if CONDITION_1 and CONDITION_2
...
endif
```

Currently I have something like below in my `configure.ac`

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([COMBINED_CONDITION],
               [test "$cond_1" != "no" -a "$cond_2" != "no"])
```

And use it as below in my Makefile.am.

```
if COMBINED_CONDITION
...
endif
```

I am fairly new to `autotools` and couldn't get the `AND`ed condition to work and want to know if it is at all possible. So far I have not been able to find any reference that suggests it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use nested `if ... endif` like

```
if CONDITION_1
if CONDITION_2
...
endif
endif
```

to implement the pseudo code

```
# pseudo code
if CONDITION_1 and CONDITION_2
...
endif
```

The same logic applies for the other three pseudo code conditions

```
# pseudo code
if CONDITION_1 and not(CONDITION_2)

if not(CONDITION_1) and CONDITION_2

if not(CONDITION_1) and not(CONDITION_2)
```

which can be implemented as e.g.

```
if CONDITION1
if !CONDITION2
...
endif
endif
```

However, the negation of a complete boolean expression cannot be expressed by nested `if ... endif`. So if you need to implement `OR` logic

```
# pseudo code
if CONDITION_1 or CONDITION_2
...
endif
```

you **cannot** apply De Morgan's law and do something purely with Automake `if ... else ... endif` because you cannot formulate a combined `else` branch. So you will need to define specially formulated `AM_CONDITIONAL` for an `OR` condition, or any other more complicated condition than a bunch of ANDs.

As an aside regarding the combined conditional, I recall `-a` and `-o` being listed as a non-portable argument to `test` and therefore

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([COMBINED_CONDITION_AND],
               [test "x$cond_1" != xno && test "x$cond_2" != xno])
AM_CONDITIONAL([COMBINED_CONDITION_OR],
               [test "x$cond_1" != xno || test "x$cond_2" != xno])
```

being recommended over

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([COMBINED_CONDITION_AND],
               [test "$cond_1" != "no" -a "$cond_2" != "no"])
AM_CONDITIONAL([COMBINED_CONDITION_OR],
               [test "$cond_1" != "no" -o "$cond_2" != "no"])
```

(See https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.71/html_node/Limitations-of-Builtins.html)

Note also the letter at the beginning of `"x$cond"` in the test arguments. This avoids unwanted results if e.g. the value of `$cond` is `-z` or `-f` or something similar which `test` would interpret. You can use any letter you want here, but `"x"` is a popular choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the values of the `CONDITION_1` and `CONDITION_2` variables will be when they are what you want you can just check them both for equality, something like:

```
ifeq ($(CONDITION_1)/$(CONDITION_2),no/no)
```

or similar.

Comment: Even when automake knows to ignore `ifeq`, how compatible is `ifeq` beyond GNU make?

Comment: Yes, if you want your automake-generated makefiles to work with non-GNU make then this won't work.  Here you're really limited by automake only, because there is no `if` etc. in POSIX standard make.  So a tag of `makefile` is not really correct for this question: everything you want to do must be handled by automake.